# How do i make images upload on web page with latest image appearing first?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, instagram

I am trying to create a web page that i can upload a new image on, which will update at the top left of the page before the rest of the images and the other images will shift one space right (like on a profile page on instagram).
I have found that it works okay with unshift()(below), and will remain within the boundaries of the web page. However it leaves a gap between the images because of the commas, i want the images bricked together so that they are flush with each other at all 4 edges (it will look like one big rectangle made of many square images) i have been trying to write a code for it all day and have been at no avail. can anyone help please? much appreciated.

```
<HTML>
<body>

<body onload="myfunction()">

<div class="content" id="content"></div>

<script>
var x = ["<img src=image1.jpg>", "<img src=image2.jpg>", "<img src=image3.jpg>", "<img src=image4>"];
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = x;

function myfunction() {
    x.unshift("<img src=image5>", "<img src=image6>");
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: might need to work some styling into it to get rid of the space

Comment: The optimal way of doing this is via a database if you want it to be sustained, but as far as the spacing is concerned, I'd just fix it with CSS. Try putting each image into a span class with no padding/margin, and setting css via jQuery.

Comment: thanks, i'll have a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use join javascript function (refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp))

http://jsfiddle.net/7z5dL/1/

```
var x = ["<img src=image1.jpg>", "<img src=image2.jpg>", "<img src=image3.jpg>", "<img src=image4>"];
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = x.join("");;

function myfunction() {
    x.unshift("<img src=image5>", "<img src=image6>");
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = x.join("");
}
```